# Man asking for food on the street would only talk to my girlfriend

Tags: conversations, united-states, awkward-situations

While in Nashville TN my girlfriend and I were approached by a man asking for money or food. We were walking down the street and he approached us from my side and asked if we could help him.

I thought he was addressing both of us but as I responded he completely ignored looking expectantly at my girlfriend and waiting for her to respond. She offered to help as well a couple of seconds later, we went to the nearest quick food place, bought some food and water and took it back to him. He thanked her and we went on our way.

I'm wondering if there's a reason for his behavior. Does anyone know if there's a reason he would only speak to my girlfriend?

Comment: Hi user24214! I edited out the 'did this happen to someone else' from your question to avoid the answers turning into a 'me too' party, but if people can find some sort of 'evidence' this is a common behaviour (and not a single incident), this question might fall under the on-topic part of 'explaining why we interact the way we do' and be much less opinion based. On the other hand, as you're describing just a single incident, it might be closed as primarily opinion based because we can't be sure what the guy asking you for money/food was thinking at the time, we can only guess...

Comment: It also might be worth noting that women are (generally speaking) more emotionally driven. The guy could’ve figured he had better luck trying to persuade her than you, because she might’ve felt more sorry. That’s just a guess. It would be better if you had more examples because this question could have good potential! :)